# What is the different between clearfix hack and overflow:hidden vs overflow:auto?

Tags: css

What is the different between `clearfix hack` and `overflow:hidden` vs `overflow:auto` ?

Are all same thing, which is best?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ed Eliot has written [the definitive guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20170716232922/http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59) on the subject.

Comment: This answer would be better if you summarized key points of the article that you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Over flow hidden will work like a charm in modern browsers even in IE7, but not IE6 and here where the clearfix method becomes handy.so if you have to target IE6 then clearfix is your friend.
here is the new clearfix hack http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/

Comment: This answer would be better if you summarized key points of the article that you linked to.