# what is the difference between 'overflow and clear to clear float?

Tags: css

html

```
<ul>
 <li> 
   <button>first part</button>
  </li>
 <li> 
   <button>second part</button>
 </li>
    <li>
    <button>third part</button>
   </li>
  </ul>
<div id="bottom">Believe Me</div>
```

css

```
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li button {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
div#bottom {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

we often use below class to clear 'float';

```
.clearfix{
  clear:both;
  overflow: hidden;
  contain: '';
}
```

sometime, we can only use 'overflow',that can solve our problem.

what difference between 'overflow' and 'clear'?

[code about this question](http://codepen.io/dukegod/pen/yONjzj)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the different between clearfix hack and overflow:hidden vs overflow:auto?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642565/what-is-the-different-between-clearfix-hack-and-overflowhidden-vs-overflowauto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange comparison since `overflow` and `clear` are completely unrelated. Unless I misunderstood your question. In which case, please rephrase so that we can clarify better.

Anyhow, overflow controls the any excess outside of the width of an element.

> The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box.

If you have a div with containing a large image and you want to restrict the image to not exceed the width of that container, overflow will do just that by giving it a `hidden` value. If you want it to scroll after a certain width or height, the `scroll` value will activate the scrollbars to allow you to do so.

`Clear` on the other hand, resets the floats.

> The clear property specifies on which sides of an element floating elements are not allowed to float.

This is particularly helpful in responsive design to center an item that has been floated to the right in larger displays but you want to reset it to the native left position for smaller devices. Of course, the use of `clear` can be determined by other factors according to your need of it.

The example above mentioned would look like this

```
<div class="box">
  <button class="right">Hello</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.right{
   float: right;
}
@media (max-width: 420px){
   .right{
       clear: right;
   }
}
```

Comment: Overflow and clear are SO completely unrelated that there are lots of articles about how they interact. For instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642565/what-is-the-different-between-clearfix-hack-and-overflowhidden-vs-overflowauto

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you had floated element("button") inside a "li". "clear" is float's sister property, the element which is set to this property will adjust itself by clearing the adjacent floated elements. floated elements can affect the container elements height. As per your example which is "li" tag. overflow method is one of the technique to solve this problem. Read more about float here: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/